# Antonym of "upright" to describe the position of a phone

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, image-identification

I have an issue with describing the following way of holding a telephone.

As held in the picture below, I would describe it as "upright"

[image: phone upright]

However, I need to describe what it is like when it is held like this

[image: phone opposite of downright]

The definition I've found for downright, which seems to me as being the correct word, is as follows (from Merriam Webster):

> Definition of downright
>
> 1 archaic :  straight down
>
> 2 absolutely : downright handsome downright mean
>
> 3 obsolete :  forthright

which doesn't seem to fit the meaning I want to convey.

Comment: It's *upside down* or *inverted*.

Comment: Welp. Thanks a lot for the suggestion - sometimes the answer is so obvious you cannot see it :-)

Comment: @Lawrence: If you add your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @JesperBangshoit *Done*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say that your picture is *upside down* or *inverted*.

> **Upside down** *adverb & adjective*
> With the upper part where the lower part should be; in an inverted position.
> (as adverb) ‘the car rolled and landed upside down’
> (as adjective) ‘an upside-down canoe’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/upside_down)
>
> **Invert** *verb*
> Put upside down or in the opposite position, order, or arrangement.
> ‘The roof is essentially inverted or turned upside down compared to the standard roofing.’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/invert)